# Can a X.509 Certificate be signed by two CAs with the same key?

Tags: certificate, openssl, certificate-authority

I have set up a private CA to sign local certificates. In the CA certificate is a, let's say, typo that I want to fix in future versions of the CA but I want to keep the already issued certificates trusted.

So let's say I gave Alice the root CA cert so my issued certs are trusted by her. Now I make the new version of the CA without the typo with the same private key that I generated the first CA with. I give the new CA version to Bob.

Is it possible to have a single issued certificate be trusted by each Alice and Bob?

How would the OpenSSL command for that look like?

Answer (score 0):

A certificate's uniqueness is defined by the combination of its public key and subject.  If you change either, it is a different certificate.  If you keep both the same, but change something else, then they are considered the same certificates.  The same goes for a CA, which is again defined by a the combination of its public key and subject in its own certificate, and the issuer field and signature field (which is derived from the CA's key amongst other things) in issued certificates.

A certificate has only one issuer field and one signature field, which means a single certificate can only be singed by one CA.  Note that an entity can have multiple certificates, signed by different CAs, but that's not relevant here.

In your case, as your public key is fixed, if you change the subject then you have a different certificate and hence it is a different CA.

If the typo is, for example, the wrong year in the expiry date then you could do as you're suggesting.  You then issue a single certificate to your end-entity from either CA and it will be trusted by both Alice and Bob.  The chain of trust will, of course, expire at different times in this example.

This is still a bit of a hack though.  If you want to fix this, issue the same Root CA certificate to both Alice and Bob and remove the original form Alice's trust-anchor store.

Answer (score 0):

**IF** in addition to the keypair, the *name* of the CA (in Subject and Issuer fields) remains exactly the same (no 'typo' there), and if (any of) the existing child certs used the issuer+serial form of AKI (which is likely if you used openssl) then also the serial number, then **YES**. See e.g.:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17331/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-ca-without-having-to-reissue-all-of-the-derived-certi
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/234547/impact-of-root-certificate-renewal
https://serverfault.com/questions/861975/re-issuing-self-signed-root-ca-without-invalidating-certificates-signed-by-it

To do this with `openssl` there are 3 approaches:

1. follow the usual procedure for creating a selfsigned cert from an existing key: `openssl req -new -x509` specifying the key in the config file or with `-key` (but *not* `-newkey`). Specify the subject (and issuer) name in the config file with `prompt=no` or with `-subj` -- but either way you must get it exactly right. Specify serial if needed (or wanted) with `-set_serial`. Specify validity with `-days`. Specify extensions in the config file (selected by `x509_extensions` in the config or `-extensions` on the commandline), or in 1.1.1 only with `-addext`.

   The config file for `req` must be accessible as a file by the program, but not necessarily a 'real' (permanent) file. In particular on Unix with some shells you can use process substitution `<(...)` (or in zsh `=(...)`) to create a temporary file with possibly dynamic contents. There are quite a few As on several stacks about using that technique to supply SAN on the commandline before (or without) 1.1.1.
2. use `openssl x509 -x509toreq -in oldcert -signkey keyfile -out csr` (you can use stdin and stdout redirection instead of `-in -out`) followed by `openssl x509 -in csr -req -signkey keyfile [-set_serial n] -days d -extfile file [-extensions section] -out newcert` (ditto). You can combine these as a pipe: `openssl x509 -x509toreq ... | openssl x509 -req ...`. For the second step you can instead use `openssl req -in csr -x509` (without `-new`) and other options the same as #1, but in 1.1.0 up you must specify the input CSR file explicitly not by redirection or piping.
3. use `openssl x509 -in oldcert -signkey keyfile -clrext -extfile file [-extensions section]`. This will automatically keep the serial; you can't change it even if you want. This also has an option `-preserve_dates` in 1.1.1 only to keep the existing validity period instead of setting a new one starting now.

To be clear, the result will enable a child cert to be *trusted* only if it is in itself a valid CA cert. If your 'typo' fix is to change BasicConstraints from ca:true to ca:false -- which *I* would not consider a 'typo' -- then the result will *chain* correctly with an existing child but will not *validate* it, because a child cert issued by a non-CA cert is not valid.